# Change IMG SRC based on referrer URL using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, src, referrer

I'm not the best at this, but I'm wanting to know if there is a way to change an image src based on the referrer URL using javascript. I've pieced this together, but it's not working and I'm not sure why. Thanks

```js
<script>
  var ref = document.refferer;
   if(ref.includes("dev.mastercoolproducts.com")){
     $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#fc-logo").attr("src","https://essickair.foxycart.com/cache?url=https://www.dropboxusercontent.com/s/uhy2eoxjojeqwsj/mc-logo.png?dl=0");
       });
   }else{
     $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#fc-logo").attr("src","https://essickair.foxycart.com/cache?url=https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/q635dlso4f8pdol/ac-color.png?dl=0");
       });
     }
</script>
```

Comment: _"but it's not working and I'm not sure why"_ - Then start debugging it. Add `console.log()`s and check the values or use the debugger and step through your code.

Comment: `document.referrer` not `document.refferer`

Comment: @Andreas I was walking through the console, but couldn't discern what the issue was. It was flagging an error saying I didn't have an open bracket that I did have, so I was lost as to the issue. But thanks, I'll keep that in mind goin forward

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you may be running this code before the document is initialized. You only want to run the code to check if your document is initialized once. I've modified your code, and think this should solve it:

```
//Only run once the document is ready
$(document).ready(function() {
  // this sets the value to '' if refferrer is somehow empty
  var ref = document.refferer || '';
  // since you'll be searching for this node multiple times, just store it in a variable:
  var logoImg = $("#fc-logo");
  if (ref.includes("dev.mastercoolproducts.com")) {
    logoImg.attr("src", "https://essickair.foxycart.com/cache?url=https://www.dropboxusercontent.com/s/uhy2eoxjojeqwsj/mc-logo.png?dl=0");
  } else {
    logoImg.attr("src", "https://essickair.foxycart.com/cache?url=https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/q635dlso4f8pdol/ac-color.png?dl=0");
  }
})
```

Comment: Dude this fixed it. Thanks so much!